# Wireless disabled: HardBlock

Tags: wireless-networking, fedora

I'm experiencing the Wireless HardBlock problem. I posted this question when I was using Ubuntu 11.10 on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102523/wireless-is-disabled) and no hope!

Here are some solved problems which I tried, but they didn't work for me: ([1](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12072941#post12072941),[2](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1419416),[3](http://glonek.co.uk/linux-mint/wireless-disabled-stuck-in-phy0-hard-blocked/))

I'm using now Fedora 17 alongside Xubuntu where I have no problem with my wireless card. Can anyone give me hope to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Slide the little switch on the side of the laptop to "ON"...

or, if you don't have an off/on switch for your wireless, look for a <kbd>Fn</kbd> key, and a little picture on the number keys of the keyboard.  One of those likely has a little wireless tower....

Hold down <kbd>Fn</kbd>, then press the key with the wireless tower picture on it.

Check your wireless.  If it's still not working, try this again, maybe you toggled it twice or something.

Comment: please be more smart !....I know these tiny mistakes could happen and I 've tried it million times before asking !,Don't worry any more I realized that there is hardware incompatibility with wireless card because this problem happens suddenly while working on either Linux OS,or Windows OS and I erased Fedora forever ! Thanks all

Comment: Can't read your mind, you didn't say you tried that. {Grin}  Sometimes have to start small.  Sorry it didn't work out with Fedora.  Better luck next time.