# Linux Mint gets stuck when using wireless card "rt73usb"

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, network-adapter

I'm changing Linux distributions a lot, wishing to resolve my problems with the wireless card identified as `rt73usb`, like explained in [this question of mine](https://superuser.com/questions/444758/wireless-disabledhardblock).

Now I'm using Linux Mint 12. I noticed something strange: When my wireless card is blocked or disabled while working, the whole laptop gets stuck. When I press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> to move to a shell, messages say:

```
phy0->rt2x00usb_vendor_request:Error-Vendor request 0X0[7,6,1"one of
them"] failed for offest 0X[3034,3000,0000] with error -71
```

and also:

```
phy0->rt73usb_load_firmware:Error-failed to write firmware to device.
```

See here:

[image]

What could be the problem? An incompatible driver? I tried to download a new driver for `rt73usb` from a [website](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/rt73usb) and installed it, but it finished with "failed"!